# In html table, insert image that's file name with some certain words

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I want to insert a image file in to a html table, file name is `?FL GR ?.jpg` (could be any words or no word) but I can not.

**Code is below**

```
<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">
    var test = *'FL%20GR%20'*
    document.write('<td style="vertical-align: top; height: 362px; width: 538px;"><img style="width: 564px; height: 354px;" alt="123" src=' + './pic%20vid/123/' + test + '.jpg' + '><br></td>')
</SCRIPT>
```

The purpose of this script is I can always show image that is with some certain words of file name without modifying html scripts, for example:
(1) This time I put `1FL GR 1.jpg` in folder `/pic vid/123/`, the html table can show image of `1FL GR 1.jpg` 
(2) I delete `1FL GR 1.jpg`, and then put `2FL GR 2.jpg` in the same folder, refresh the html, the html table can show image of `2FL GR 2.jpg`.

Comment: First, that is javascript, not java. Second, I think it is not possible to load an image just by a pattern... what if multiple images match that pattern?

Comment: You cannot do that, and It would not make any sense anyways. If the image is deleted, It will not dissapear on the web browser unless you refresh. And if you refresh the page, just make the server return any other of the existing images.

Comment: there will be ONLY ONE file match "?FL GR ?.jpg" in the same folder. for example (1) this time I put "1FL GR 1.jpg" in folder "/pic vid/123/", the html table can show image of "1FL GR 1.jpg" (2) I DELETE "1FL GR 1.jpg", and then put "2FL GR 2.jpg" in the same folder, refresh the html, the html table can show image of "2FL GR 2.jpg".

Comment: @Julio Thank for comment, if the image delete, I will put another "?FL GR?.jpg" in the folder "/pic vid/123/". or I can say, in folder "/pic vid/123/", there is always a image file that name is "?FL GR?.jpg".

Comment: @PythonCW Can you modify the server/backend? Just make the server read the directory and return the name of the new image that matches your needs.

Comment: @Julio, thanks for you comment. I can modify the server but it is not the key point. actually I would like to create a html template with some tables include files, for example, this time I have 20170712.html with "Xtable+1FL1GR.jpg","Ytable+1HI1BL.jpg", and etc.. (2) and next time I would like to have 20180713.html with  "Xtable+2FL2GR.jpg","Ytable+2HI2BL.jpg", and etc..(3) So, if I have this good template, I do not need to modify html image source every time.

Comment: So, can't you add some server-side scripting into the template?

Comment: Thanks for all comments, I will do in another way (1) use python to create a txt file that has names of all image files in the folder "/pic vid/123/" (2) use javascript to read the txt and find which one filename is like "?FL?GR?.jpg" (3) then can put the file name in html image src=